# Zeroes of f(x) in a splitting field $E $ have the same multiplicity

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over a field $F$ and let $E$ be a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$. Then all the zeroes of $f(x)$ in $E$ have the same multiplicity.

The proof of this theorem involves the following steps

Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct zeroes of $f(x)$ in $E.$ If $a$ has multiplicity $m,$ then in $E[x]$, we may write $f(x)= (x-a)^m g(x)$. It follows from a lemma that there is a field isomorphism from E to itself that carries a to b and acts as the identity on $F.$

> Thus, $f(x)= \Phi(f(x))= (x-b)^m \Phi(g(x))$

I am not able to understand the above step. I understand that $a$ is carried to b by an isomorphism. But why is $\Phi(x-a)= x-b $

> **EDIT:** Suppose the isomorphism is extended to $E[x]$ such that $\Phi(x)=x$. Does this mean that the required result of the theorem is true only when $\Phi(x)=x$ and not for all other isomorphism mappings ?

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a homomorphism $\varphi:F\to K$, where $F,K$ are fields (or rings), there is an induced homomorphism $\Phi:F[x]\to K[x]$, which is defined by $\Phi|_F=\varphi,\;\Phi(x)=x$.
Obviously we get $\Phi(x-a)=\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)=x-b$.

Comment: But, the problem statement mentions  $\Phi$  as the isomorphism from $E \rightarrow E$, which is an identity on the units of $F$. Is it right for us to extend $\Phi$ to $E[x]$?

Comment: If $\Phi$ is from $E$ to $E$, then $\Phi(x-a)$ is not defined, since $x\not\in E$. The only thing we can do is extend $\Phi$ to $E[x]$.

Comment: Oh okay .. does that mean, that the result in the theorem is true only when the isomorphism mapping $\Phi$ is such that $\Phi(x) = x$?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: okay... shouldn't have the theorem statement mentioned this explicitly specially when it's valid for only a special case of a isomorphism mapping?

Comment: Well, I guess it's just a very common and familiar extension, so by abuse of notation, when the same letter is used for a map $E\to E$ and a map $E[x]\to E[x]$, one is expected to understand.

Answer (score 2):

In fact $\Phi$ is an isomorphism of $E$, it is extended to  $E[x]$ by $\Phi(x)=x$, so $\Phi(x-a)=\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)=x-b$.

Comment: Oh do you mean to say that we took $\Phi$ such that $\Phi(x)=x$?